# Applet Location (x,y coordinates) on screen

Tags: java, browser, applet

Is there a way how to get the x,y coordinates on the screen of an applet which is embeded in the browser, the reason for this is that the applet records the screen of the user but right now it is recording the whole desktop.

I need the applet to record only the browser window.

Is this possible?

```
Button coor = new Button("Action");
add(coor);
Point loc = new Point();
loc = coor.getLocationOnScreen();
showStatus(Integer.toString(loc.x));
showStatus(Integer.toString(loc.y));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Component.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29).

Comment: so in the applet I have to do this.getLocationOnScreen()?

Comment: *"I have to do this.getLocationOnScreen()?"* Yes.

Comment: Hi Andrew I tried creating a button in the applet and used getLocationOnScreen but it gives me the coordinates of 0,0 which is not right.

The code I used is something like the following:
Button coor = new Button("Action");
add(coor);
coor.getLocationOnScreen();

and it gives me coor.x = 0, coor.y = 0

Comment: *"The code I used is"*  I cannot read code in comments, edit it into the question and use code formatting.  But rather than code snippets, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Post an SSCCE (and I will look further at it).